# Problem with php pager

Tags: php, pager

I made a simple table class with pager for my project in php. It works fine if the page address does not contain any params passed by `GET` method. Here is the way Im creating the table with pager

```
$tbl = new table();
$tbl->headers(array ("Header1", "Header2"));
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$tbl->pager(15, $query);           
$tbl->page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$query = "SELECT id, name, FROM table";
$tbl->createTable($query);
```

I want to use it in the `switch` function

```
switch ($_GET['a']) {
        case b:
            $tbl = new table();
            $tbl->headers(array ("Header1", "Header2"));
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
            $tbl->pager(15, $query);

            $tbl->page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $query = "SELECT id, name, FROM table";
            $tbl->createTable($query);
            break;
        case c:
            ...
            break;
    }
```

and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will pass `page.php?a=b` to the pager and create pager as it should be. Problem occurs when I switch between pages because `REQUEST_URI` each time pass `page.php?a=b` + actual page number I am on to the pager so the address looks like `pager.php?a=b&page1&page=2...`. And my question is, is there a way to pass to pager only `page.php?a=b` and make it to be nonchangeable or sth like that ?? Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Is the problem that `$tbl->page` is supposed to identify the URL being viewed, independent of the query string?

Comment: Yes. As in the example I want it to allways be `page.php?a=b` but Its allway adding new param to url when I switch the page. That is why Im asking about other way to pass the actual page without page number in url

Comment: You should check out ngDesk instead as its totally free and has awesome features. You can check it out here https://www.ngdesk.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sd

```
function getQE(){
     if($_GET){ 
       // exlude some variables from $_GET (pass names of variables in function call)
       $ex = func_get_args();
       $qstr  = "?";
       foreach($_GET as $key=>$value) {
          if (!in_array($key, $ex)){
              $qstr .= $key."=".$value;
              $qstr .= '&';
          }
       }
     }
return $qstr;
}
```

in your case to get query string without 'page' you should call this function like this:

```
$get = getQE('page');
```

if you need to exclude more than one:

```
$get = getQE('page', 'section','folder');
```

Comment: Great! I had absolutely the same problem some time ago and I writen this function... I'm glad it helped you too :)